# How to show rsync progress when running as systemd service

Tags: bash, systemd, rsync, stdout

I have a bash script `sync_nodes.sh` that I want to manage with a systemd unit `sync_nodes.service`.

I want the progress of of the `rsync` command to show up in my logs. When I run the command interactively I get one progress record every second which is what I want; however, when I run the `sync_nodes.service` the progress information isn't sent to the journal until the very end when the rsync job is finished.

`sync_nodes.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo starting...
for host in 192.168.42.3{0,1,2}
do
        rsync \
        --progress \
        --archive \
        --delete \
        --compress \
        -e 'ssh -i /home/ops/private_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
        /home/ops/code/ \
        "ops@${host}:/home/ops/code/" \
        | stdbuf --output L tr '\r' '\n' \
        | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//'
done
```

When I run `sync_nodes.sh` interactivley the status information I want is printed

```
$ ./sync_nodes.sh
starting...
sending incremental file list
sending incremental file list
sending incremental file list
./
model.data

32,768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00
21,233,664   1%   20.22MB/s    0:00:50
42,565,632   3%   20.29MB/s    0:00:49
62,193,664   5%   19.77MB/s    0:00:49
# ...
```

`sync_nodes.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ops/sync_nodes.sh
SyslogIdentifier=sync_nodes
```

Starting the unit

```
sudo systemctl start sync_nodes.service
```

Looking at the journal output:

```
$ sudo journalctl -f -u sync_nodes
Sep 11 20:25:58 srv0 systemd[1]: Starting sync_nodes.service...
Sep 11 20:25:58 srv0 sync_nodes[6138]: starting...
Sep 11 20:25:58 srv0 systemd[1]: Started sync_nodes.service.
Sep 11 20:25:59 srv0 sync_nodes[6138]: sending incremental file list
Sep 11 20:25:59 srv0 sync_nodes[6138]: sending incremental file list
```

Eventually at the very end all the status is printed to the journal but only after the transfer is finished. I want the progress to be printed periodically.

How do I show the rsync progress periodically in journald?

Comment: Personally I think you'd be better off with `--verbose` (`-v`) instead of `--progress`.

Comment: Why? `--verbose` does not show the progress of the transfer

Comment: You'll not get an interactive progress marker except interactively.

Comment: is it possible to trick rsync into thinking it's being run interactively?